# SQL how do I remove trailing spaces?

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim, trailing

I'm currently working in an SQL database where a column has trailing spaces.

The spaces in question show up as %20 in the browser url.

I've been able to remove them with a select query but whenever I convert it to an update an set query it doesn't seem to work, any input would be appreciated.

Working select query:

```
select [dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control](identifier)
from [AHDRC].[dbo].[artworks]
```

Broken update query:

```
update [AHDRC].[dbo].[artworks]
SET [identifier] = [dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control](identifier);                                         

SELECT [identifier]
From [AHDRC].[dbo].[artworks];
```

I am currently using SQL server management studio
[identifier] is a nchar(128)

Apologies if anything is unclear / badly formatted.

Comment: This looks like sql server, please tag your dbms

Comment: Is it a `char`? That is a fixed length datatype, where a value shorter than its defined length is padded with spaces

Comment: @HoneyBadger I've added your remarks, I'm using SQL server management studio 18 & [identifier] is a nvarchar(max).

Comment: SQL server management studio is an editor, not a dbms. The dbms would be sql server. `string` is not a sql server datatype, its `(n)vartchar` or `(n)char`

Comment: @HoneyBadger You hit the nail on the head with the char padding with spaces, thanks a lot for the explanation & additional info.

Answer (score 0):

[identifier] was a nchar(128) causing trailing spaces.